# Creating a local vimrc for a large LaTeX project with selective plugins, settings, and mappings

Tags: vimrc, default-settings

This is related to my previous question that [you can find here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/41525/when-to-use-set-exrc-and-local-vimrc-in-vim-and-how-to-manage-plugins-with):

I am currently working on a large project (a PhD thesis with multiple chapters, each consisting of around 30 pages) and have found that my VIM setup, which includes numerous plugins, settings, and mappings for general use, is causing noticeable slowdown when scrolling through pages.

To address this, I want to create a local `vimrc` file specifically for this project, where most of the plugins are disabled except for a few essential ones: `vimtex, deoplete, and undotree`.

Additionally, I'd like to disable some of the settings and/or mappings that I have saved in `~/.vim/mappings.vim` and `vimrc` files, but only for this specific project. I still want the settings I have for `.tex` files saved in `.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim` to be available, as well as some functions that I've kept separate in `.vim/autoload/`.

My question is: What is the best approach to achieve this selective setup for my LaTeX project? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: With delay loading most of the plugin should not be loaded if you only edit TeX files. Did you identified what is the plugin that makes the edition of the large TeX file slow (for startup the [startuptime](https://github.com/dstein64/vim-startuptime) plugin may help)?

Comment: From your question, I don't understand whether you already split your large thesis into one file per chapter using [`\include`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250/166178). If not, you might consider doing so.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt here is the `startuptime`: https://pasteboard.co/iZSo7r9K7vOq.png and here is the `.vimrc`: https://pastebin.com/9mLLfZth

Comment: In what unit is the time expressed?

Comment: @romainl according to the developer of the plugin `Times are in milliseconds.`

Comment: You should identify the cause of the slowdown before considering such an ambitious and, essentially, impossible move. This is pure XY: you experience a slowdown -> you have no idea what causes it -> you consider something crazy -> you ask about that crazy solution instead of asking about your slowdown issue.